# Unable to load an image in the browser with asp.net webform control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

My image is hosted inside the listview.

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("BannerPath","AffiliateBanners/{0}") %>' Width="100" Height="100" runat="server" />
```

The listview works well. It fetches and displays all the items.

The problem is that the image isnt loaded.

I checked the path of the image, it is the right path and the image loads.

The strange thing is after loading the image in the browser by copying and pasting the image path from the browser inspector (Chrome/Firefox), and browsing back.. the image loads successfully on the page.

Why is that? and how can I make it load ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these (probably the 2nd or 3rd one, or something similar):

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("BannerPath","~/AffiliateBanners/{0}") %>'

ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("AffiliateBanners/{0}", Eval("BannerPath")) %>'

ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("~/AffiliateBanners/{0}", Eval("BannerPath")) %>'
```